# PYTHONPATH as agrument to python interpreter

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I want to pass PYTHONPATH as argument to python.exe just like i can do this in java:

`java -classpath /somedir/some.jar;/anotherdir MyClass`

so i'm looking for something like:

`python -PYTHONPATH /somedir/pythonsrc;/anotherdir/pythonsrc mymodule.py`

is it possible to do such a think in python?
thanks

Comment: That's not possible like that but why not use old good `set PYTHONPATH=...`?

Comment: that's because i have multiple python apps and i want a simple command line (not "fancy" batch scripts because they have their own disadvantages) i want a simple command line to run each of my apps with different libraries! that seems to me like the first requirement of a program language, i use this so much in java, java -cp mylibraries myclass.  i have multiple python apps with different languages! i need to run each with its own command line - no batch script!!! i find it unbelievable there is no such option! can you help?

Comment: See [Setting environment variable for just one command in Windows cmd.exe](http://superuser.com/questions/223104/)

Comment: The question is still relevant. I have a bash script that spawns a subprocess to run Python and feeds its output into another Python process. It would be great to set different `PYTHONPATH`s explicitly, because my "general" PYTHONPATH includes a relative path (`.` -- always nice to have, but may interfere with other libs) but they are executed in different directories.
However, it's still not possible to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the environement variable PYTHONPATH before launching python :

On windows :

```
set PYTHONPATH=/somedir/pythonsrc;/anotherdir/pythonsrc && python.exe mymodule.py
```

On unix

```
PYTHONPATH=/somedir/pythonsrc:/anotherdir/pythonsrc python mymodule.py
```

Comment: You can use `PYTHONPATH=... python mymodule.py` to set the variable just for that invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new shell using `/C` option.

```
cmd.exe /C "set PYTHONPATH=/somedir/pythonsrc && python.exe mymoudle.py"
```